# DocuSign and Manage Service Desk Plus Integration

Tags: rest, api, docusignapi

I need some guidance for integrating DocuSign and Service Desk Plus. This will be my first time working with APIs.

I would like to have Manage Engine Service Desk Plus (SDP) send information over to DocuSign. This information will then be used to create a PDF that will be sent by DocuSign to a user.

So far I have been using Postman's POST function to pull the information I need from SDP. I have also used the same function to create envelopes and send envelopes with DocuSign.

I am unable to understand how to get the information I retrieved using Postman from SDP to DocuSign.

Please let me know if there is any other information that I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Good work on getting the data you want out of Service Desk by using Postman.

That is an important first step.

Next, choose a software language (I suggest a scripting style language such as PHP, Python, Node or Ruby) and write a software program that pulls the same data from Service Desk programmatically.

Then convert the information to PDF (there are many libraries for doing so).

Or just create an HTML file with the data since DocuSign can convert the HTML file to PDF for you. As an example of this, check out line 203 of this [example Node.js file](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt/blob/master/lib/DS_Work.js).

Then call the DocuSign Envelopes::create API method to send your envelope.

Please open new questions on StackOverflow if you run into problems.